Пишу бота, он дает слово на английском и три попытки написать его перевод, ошибка в том, что если неверно бот не дает возможности повторно написать
@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'да':
        dictionary = {}
        with open('ENRUS1.TXT', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
                english_word = lines[i].strip()
                russian_translation = lines[i + 1].strip()
                dictionary[english_word] = russian_translation

        english_word = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
        correct_translation = dictionary[english_word]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Переведите слово {english_word}')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_anser, correct_translation, english_word)

def on_anser(message, correct_translation, english_word):
    attempts = 3
    for i in range(attempts):
        user_translation = message.text.lower()
        user_words = user_translation.split()
        correct_words = set(correct_translation.lower().split())

        is_correct = any(word in correct_words for word in user_words)

        english_word1 = english_word.split()

        if is_correct and len(user_words) == len(english_word1):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Верно')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_anser, correct_translation, english_word)
        else:
            if attempts - i - 1 != 0:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Неверно! Осталось {attempts - i - 1} попытки')
            if attempts - i - 1 == 0:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Неверно. Правильный перевод: {correct_translation}')

